# Typescript imports for valiatorjs failing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types

I'm using validator JS with typescript.  These are the deps:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/validator": "^12.0.1",
    "validator": "^12.2.0"
  }
```

When I try to import `isDividibleBy` like this:

```
import { isDivisibleBy } from "validator";
```

I get this error:

```
    src/is.ts:16:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../../Github/istest/is/node_modules/@types/validator"' has no exported member 'isDivisibleBy'. Did you mean to use 'import isDivisibleBy from "../../../../Github/istest/is/node_modules/@types/validator"' instead?
```

This also produces an error:

```
import isDivisibleBy from 'validator'
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current type definitions for ValidatorJS were outdated.  I implemented a new project that converts all of ValidatorJS to typescript and builds it using the Angular Package Format, so that we get all the popular package formats for free in addition to typing:

https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validatorts